# « [...] in the higher service of the national interest » / pour le « service supérieur de l'intérêt national » : analyse de la traduction ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs, formulation-idiomatique, politique

On a pu lire dans les médias des [extraits](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/feb/17/theresa-may-letter-conservative-mps-attempts-unite-warring-party) de propos de la Première ministre du Royaume-Uni, Mme Theresa May, concernant les modalités du [*Brexit*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A9dure_de_retrait_du_Royaume-Uni_de_l%27Union_europ%C3%A9enne)<sup>1</sup> :

> Instead [NDLR *of exiting the EU without a deal or an implementation period*], our party can do what it has done so often in the past: move
>   beyond what divides us and come together behind what unites us;
>   sacrifice if necessary our own personal preferences **in the higher
>   service of the national interest**; and rise to the level of events in a
>   way that restores the faith of the British people in our political
>   process.
>
> [ Propos de la Première ministre tels que rapportés dans *The
>   Guardian*, je souligne et ajoute un extrait d'un paragraphe précédent
>   entre crochets ]

Dans [*La Presse*](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201902/16/01-5215028-brexit-may-va-parler-aux-dirigeants-de-tous-les-etats-membres-de-lue.php) (via l'AFP) on a paraphrasé un segment du propos comme suit :

> Les responsables conservateurs doivent sacrifier « leurs préférences
>   personnelles » pour le « service supérieur de l'intérêt national »,
>   a-t-elle écrit. (La Presse)

- Cette traduction ressemblant au mot à mot est-elle adéquate, bien
  sentie, vu entre autres le sens du mot [*service*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/service) ou sa
  collocation plus typique avec la [*patrie*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/service/610790), l'apport à première
  vue inusité de l'adjectif *supérieur* au *service*, et l'emploi de la
  préposition *pour* afin d'unir les deux parties de citation ?
- Devait-on préférer quelque chose de possiblement [plus usuel](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20*%2Cservice%20sup%C3%A9rieur%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20du%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20et%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20dont%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20d%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAts%20sup%C3%A9rieurs%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cservice%20sup%C3%A9rieur%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bservice%20sup%C3%A9rieur%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bservice%20sup%C3%A9rieur%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bservice%20sup%C3%A9rieur%20des%3B%2Cc0) comme les « intérêts supérieurs de la nation » (ex. au Québec [1](https://quebec.huffingtonpost.ca/gerard-montpetit/la-maison-johnson-symbole-des-interets-superieurs-du-quebec_a_23468191/), [2](https://www.lepacte.ca/medias-738136-521482-549739.html)) ?

...peut-on justifier et au besoin reformuler au long la phrase
   (*sacrifice... national interest*) ou paraphraser comme le fait *La
   Presse* ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> ...dont le [référendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit#Referendum_of_2016) tenu le 23 juin 2016 (soit la veille de la Fête nationale du Québec, la Saint-Jean-Baptiste) a fait l'objet d'[allégations d'influence de la Russie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_interference_in_the_2016_Brexit_referendum) qui sont toujours [sous enquête](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_electoral_intervention#United_Kingdom_Brexit_referendum_(Russia,_2016)).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

*L'intérêt supérieur de la nation*, *les intérêts supérieurs de la nation* ou même simplement *l'intérêt national* sont en effet des locutions consacrées que personnellement je préférerais au mot-à-mot.

Il n'y a pas besoin de reformuler la phrase au long : on peut dire

> sacrifier si nécessaire nos propres préférences personnelles **au bénéfice de l'intérêt supérieur de la nation**

Comment: Oui ce n'est à mon sens pas une bonne traduction, même si on comprend le sens. Celle que vous proposez est la bonne.